# Electron Tauon Feynman Diagram

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

I want to understand why the following Feynman Diagram is not allowed in the standart model:[image: feynamn diagram e->t by Z]

My thoughts on why it is allowed is we can have this interaction:
[image]

Comment: Search term: "flavor-changing neutral current".

Comment: thx, so the idea is similar to the one of the neutrino oscillation?

Comment: What is "electon"?

Comment: *"so the idea is similar to the one of the neutrino oscillation"* No. Neutrino oscillation does not involve particles other than the neutrinos. A Feynman diagram for neutrino oscillation (which would be pointless to draw as it wouldn't express a perturbation series for calculating anything) would be a straight line labeled with one neutrino species at one end and a different species at the other. No boson involved.

Answer (score -1):

Flavor changing neutral currents can not occur because a Z boson can only change a mass of a particle and it only changes certain things. The W boson however changes charge and mass and this overrides certain things and lets the particle change flavor.

Comment: How do you claim that *Z* changes a mass of a particle?

Comment: Z changes mass of particle because a Z boson has rest mass and if a particle emits another particle with mass it will lose mass.

Comment: The *Z* in both diagrams is virtual, to any well-meaning reader.

Comment: It is an off-shell z boson, but even if it is off shell it carries some mass and energy. Maybe not the exact 90 Mev mass.

Comment: It carries a four-momentum, in general off-shell. The reason that Feynman-diagram vertex is excluded from the standard model is the necessary flavor diagonal-nature of such vertices, not  a spurious imagined mass balance.

Comment: The energy difference between in this example the tau and the electron was converted into neutrinos. Of course this decay is impossible because flavor changing neutral currents are impossible.